# Gurobi MIP : how to select the variables on which to branch

Tags: cplex, gurobi

I use Gurobi 7.02 to solve MIP. I'd like to choose a set of variables on which to branch (I'm very confident that it will ease the solving).

In fact I'm looking for the equivalent in Gurobi for CPLEX's `mip.strategy.variableselect`

Does anyone knows something about it?

Thanks for you attention

Answer (score 0):

You can find a comparison of Gurobi and CPLEX parameters in the [Switching from CPLEX web page](http://www.gurobi.com/resources/switching-to-gurobi/switching-from-cplex).  In particular, `VarBranch` is similar to `CPX_PARAM_VARSEL`.  However, that page also explains the following:

> Gurobi and CPLEX use different strategies and algorithms. Gurobi strategy tuning may differ from the CPLEX tuning you've done, and often it may not be necessary at all. We recommend that you start with default settings, and only change parameters when you observe specific behavior that you'd like to modify.